# sending image to mail by java program without attaching?

Tags: jakarta-ee

i would like to know about how to send images to mail by java program. i can send text and images but it displays as attached file..
i want it should come as past of my text...
the following is which i used

```
// Create new message with mail session.  
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);  

// Create multipart message.  
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  

// Create bodypart.  
BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  

// Create the HTML with link to image CID.  
// Prefix the link with "cid:".  
String str = "<html><h1>Hello</h1>" +  
            "<img src=\"cid:image_cid\"></html>";  

// Set the MIME-type to HTML.  
bodyPart.setContent(str, "text/html");  

// Add the HTML bodypart to the multipart.  
multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);  

// Create another bodypart to include the image attachment.  
bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();  

// Read image from file system.  
DataSource ds = new FileDataSource("C:\\images\\image.png");  
bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(ds));  

// Set the content-ID of the image attachment.  
// Enclose the image CID with the lesser and greater signs.  
bodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_cid>");  

// Add image attachment to multipart.  
multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);  

// Add multipart content to message.  
message.setContent(multipart);  

// Now set the header and send the email.  
...
```

please tell me if any one knows..

thanks in adv

Answer (score 5):

All what you are doing is correct, I'm using gmail and I need click on "Display Images" to see images in emails, you can add following line to see image:

```
mbp2.setFileName("image.png");
```

My full code looks as this:

```
    // create a message
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    msg.setSubject(subject);

    // create and fill the first message part
    MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp1.setContent(bodyText, "text/html");

    // create the second message part
    MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();
    // attach the file to the message
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File("image.png"));
        mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        mbp2.setFileName("image.png");
        mbp2.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image_cid>"); // cid:image_cid
    // create the Multipart and add its parts to it
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp2);
    // add the Multipart to the message
    msg.setContent(mp);
    // send the message
    Transport.send(msg);
```

and html message body is this:

```
bodyText = "<p><img style='float:right' src='cid:image_cid'>Hello World example</p>";
```