# Mail sent with java contain incorrect html sign

Tags: java, html-email, jakarta-mail

in my program I must send a mail using java. The program send correctly the mail but the server add automatically a sign. The result is that the received email contains the correct body but the signature with html tags.

```
Correct body.....
</pre>
<html>
<i>
Sent by me
<i>
<br>
<br>
</html>
```

I sent the mail with the follow code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail." + protocol + ".host", smtpHost);
    props.put("mail." + protocol + ".port", smtpPort);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    // Construct the message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, loadAddress());
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setText(body);

    // Send the message
    props.put("mail." + protocol + ".auth", "false");
    Transport t = session.getTransport(protocol);
    try {
        t.connect();
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } finally {
        t.close();
    }
```

EDIT: I'm trying to insert the follow code:

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText(body);
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    msg.setContent(multipart);
```

But the result doesn't change. The function where I create the body is:

```
public void setBody(ArrayList<User> users) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    subject = new String("Day " + formattedDate);
    body += "Hi "
        + formattedDate;    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with [MimeBodyPart.setContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setContent(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: you could refer the link below 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942575/sending-image-to-mail-by-java-program-without-attaching

Comment: can you past the part where you save the body?

Comment: I assume it's not possible to contact your mail server's admin and check if they can disable the signature for the account you re using?

Comment: No I can't disable the signature

Comment: I add the part where I save the body and a possible solution that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved insert the follow code:

```
MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp1.setContent(body, "text/html");
    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp1);

    msg.setContent(mp, "text/html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `.setContent(Object o, String s)` method from the Message class, put your body into the Object parameter as a String and put something like "text/html" in the second parameter to define the content-type.

Comment: I'm trying this solution but the result doesn't change